# :hover event on area and changing upper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So the title is weird so I'll try my best to explain myself.

I want to use `:hover`. I'm trying to build one of those slideshows of text and pictures which when you hover the text more text shows up and the first text go up.

Now the problems:

1. I want to refer `:hover` to upper div like when hovering one of the subtext/ids. I want to change "ShortText" property (To remove the background that the text leave behind)
2. When I use it the text become jumpy because I change the text place and make it higher so when trying to move the mouse over the div(It have background so I can the area) all the text jump up and down.
3. When hovering, I want to background to go down the amount the text went up tried to use padding/margin but it moved the text that need to be shown down.
   I think that it relate to number 2 but I'm not sure

Hope I was clear and my code show what I want to do I needed to change it because the website will be on a different language.

If needed I'll copy the code as it is. Trying to upload the website so you will be able to see it.

Can use Jquery/JS if needed

```css
#ShortText {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,.6);
}

#FirstSecond,#SecondSecond,#ThirdSecond {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
}

#FirstMain:hover {
  position:relative;
  top:-200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,.6);
  padding-bottom:200px
}

#FirstMain:hover + #FirstSecond {
  position:relative;
  top:-300px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-size:auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="ShortText">
  <div><!--This is a test to see if i use id on the div it work-->
    <h1 id="FirstMain" >First</h1>
    <p id="FirstSecond">Hoverd</p>
  </div>
  <div >
    <h1 id="SecondMain">Second</h1>
    <p id="SecondSecond">Hoverd</p>
  </div>
  <div >
    <h1 id="ThirdMain">Third</h1>
    <p id="ThirdSecond">Hoverd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saarsc/y1gdh8n2/)

Comment: When "First" is hovered what should occur ?

Comment: I want it to go up x pixels and then change the background size to down to the start of the picture and then show "FirstSecond" under "FirstMain" and the background of "FirstMain" before the hover will be removed until the mouse go off hope i was clear

Comment: Not certain interpret expected results correctly . _"then change the background size to down to the start of the picture"_ What is "picture" ?

Comment: As i said this is a part of a slideshow the text(the code here) is on the picture and the background change his let say if I take the text to 50% of the height of the picture the size of the background will be 50% down(from a little above the text to edge of the picture)

Comment: You should look into these examples, provided by the cool guys and girls from codrops: http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/

Actually you should bookmark that site and visit it weekly :-) You _will_ be inspired :-)

Comment: Looks very cool but how do I get the code from it? all of it is in here http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/11/how-to-create-a-tiled-background-slideshow/ ?